# How can I get a Vagrant provision shell script to successfully clone a mercurial repository?

Tags: shell, ssh, mercurial, vagrant, provisioning

I am trying to configure a virtual machine using Vagrant as a local development environment.

I would like the provision script to clone a Mercurial repository from Bitbucket within the guest machine.

In order to accomplish this I have added `hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo` in my [provision shell script](http://pastebin.com/aQRspdJT)

I also added the flag `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` in my [Vagrantfile](http://pastebin.com/ygk5va6Z).

However I keep getting the following error:

> ==> default: remote: Host key verification failed.
>
> ==> default: abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
>
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that
> this means the command failed. The output for this command should be
> in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.

I've successfully set up SSH keys for my Bitbucket account on my host machine but for some reason they don't seem to be forwarded in the guest machine even though I've set the flag true.

My host machine is running on Windows 7 and the guest is running on Linux Trusty Tarh

Sincerely appreciate any tips on how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Can you post your Vagrantfile too?

Comment: It might also be worth checking if your ssh-agent is running. Windows won't automatically run this unless you explicitly start your ssh-agent

Comment: Updated in question. I have Pageant running with the Bitbucket key loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the host key of bitbucket to your known_hosts file. You could either do that manually, or try something like https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts.

Hope that helps.